# What is the name for the male version of a nymphomaniac?

Tags: single-word-requests

A nymphomaniac is the word which signifies a woman with uncontrolled sexual desires. What is the best word to describe a man who demonstrates similar characteristics?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**Satyriasis**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satyriasis?s=t) (also satyromania) is the corresponding condition to *nymphomania* in men.

It is derived from the [Satyrs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/satyr) who in Greek mythology were drunken hyper-sexual goat-man creatures who were attendant upon Dionysus.

This same condition is often called [**Don Juanism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Juanism), too.  Named for the classic literary character [Don Juan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Juan), famous for his conquests with women.

Comment: Also called **satyromania**. So they can be called **satyromaniac**.

Comment: @ermanen That is true.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/satyromania

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "horny" came from the "Satyr"'s goat horns.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez It did. There are a lot of horn references in sexuality. Some are directly phallic, though.

Comment: So what would be opposite (sex) of nympho? **Satyro**?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia uses "hypersexuality":

> [hypersexuality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymphomaniac) — *"Man-crazy", "Nympho", "Nymphomaniac" and "Sexual Dependency" redirects to hypersexuality.* Hypersexuality is extremely frequent or suddenly increased sexual urges or sexual activity.

The appropriate form would then be "hypersexual".

Comment: I believe that is a general term for anyone, despite the gender, is sexually hyperactive.

Comment: But it is still the best term to call a man who is hypersexual. Why insist on a gendered term when the non sexist term is better?

Comment: @BraddSzonye because of the OPs framing of the question. They wanted a counterpoint not a catch-all. I assume they want the inherent pejorative connotation as well. Calling someone hypersexual isn't as insulting as nymphomaniac.

Comment: @david I know – I'm deliberately questioning the OP's premises, and asking him to question whether he really wants the sexism that the gendered versions of these words imply.

Comment: @BraddSzonye That seems reasonable.  There is a use for such terms, though.  Hyper-sexual is not something to call your  daughter-in-law when you're trying to convince your son she's been doing the gardner behind his back.  And, vice-versa.  You would *want* a pejorative in those cases.

Comment: @BraddSzonye What if a man referred to himself as a nympho? Wouldnt that be only a feminine term like him saying he is an actress? (Even though everyone is an actor now.) Women can 'own it' by referring to themselves as nymphos but men cannot. They are Satyrs in old world language which some people are curious to know about. Youre saying that historians wanting to know older terms are sexist and the history should be forgotten because youre a control freak? Maybe he is writing a period piece novel. This could be the reason the question was raised. Not necessarily because the asker wants to be

Answer (score -2):

Casanova, the type of man that lusts after every beautiful girl or woman.

Comment: Let's respect the original answer. Tawdry comments and other solutions should be posted in a separate answer. See edit history.

Comment: @J.Taylor That was not an edit worth accepting.

Comment: The edit history is discouraging.  So many people reverted to six-year-olds on this one.  But why did Community approve those awful edits?  Could it be that artificial intelligence has a way to go?

Comment: @ab2 In both cases, a reviewer decided to "improve edit", which makes Community approve the edit. The reviewer's edit is the one right after the one "Community" approved.